# Assigning one value to many elements of an array in Scala

Tags: scala

I have some experience with R language and now I wanted to try Scala language. In R language I can assign one value to many elements of a vector, e.g.

```
(xs <- 1:10)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
k <- 3
xs[1:k] <- xs[k+1]
xs
# 4  4  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It assigns value of k+1 element to all elements of indices from 1 to k. Is it also possible to do it without a loop in Scala (I mean Array in Scale)? I know there is slice method, but it only returns values of an Array, one cannot modify elements of the Array using this method.

What is even more, should I use Array or ArrayBuffer if I only want to change values of elements and I do not want to add/remove elements from a collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [java.util.Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int)) methods.

```
scala> val xs = (1 to 9).toArray
xs: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val k = 6
k: Int = 6

scala> java.util.Arrays.fill(xs, 0, k, xs(k))

scala> xs
res10: Array[Int] = Array(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, if not resizing the collection but editing the elements, stick with array. `ArrayBuffer` is much like the Java `ArrayList`, it resizes it self when it needs to, so insertion is amortized constant, not just constant.

For your first question, I'm not aware of any method in the collections library that would allow you to do this. It's obviously syntactic sugar for looping, so if you really care (do you *really* find yourself needing to do this often?), you can define an implicit class and yourself define a method which loops, and then use that. Write a comment if you would like to see example of such code, otherwise try doing it yourself, it's gonna be good training.

Comment: In R there is need to avoid explicite loops, as they are much more slower than built-in functions, which are loops in C++. Can I assume that there is no need to avoid loops in Scala and they are as fast as build-in methods/functions?

Comment: @bartoszukm if you really care about performance over loops, I would like to recommend https://github.com/non/spire to you, using the `cfor` macro. We use it extensively and have seen good speed increases. Essentially it compiles your loops into tail recursive functions which compiles to while loops, yielding nice syntax but still good speed.

Answer (score 1):

Scala has the `Range` class. You can convert the `Range` to an `Array` if you wish.

```
scala> val n = 10 
n: Int = 10

scala> Range(1,n)
res22: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> res22.toArray
res23: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
                    │
```

`ArrrayBuffer` has [constant time update](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) and would be good for updating values.

Comment: Why not use an `Array` if only updating values?